# How do I deserialize 24 hour date string to LocalDate using Jackson and RestTemplate

Tags: java

I have the following...

```
public static final String DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ";
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = DATE_PATTERN)
private LocalDate created;

return this.restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, SearchResult.class);
```

When I run the code it errors out with the following...

```
java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value for ClockHourOfAmPm (valid values 1 - 12): 13
    at java.base/java.time.temporal.ValueRange.checkValidValue(ValueRange.java:311) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.time.temporal.ChronoField.checkValidValue(ChronoField.java:717) ~[na:na]
```

How do I deserialize this to a LocalDate? Regular Java7 date works fine.

**The Final Solution Looks like this**

```
public static final String DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";

public class LocalDateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<LocalDate>{
    protected LocalDateDeserializer(){
        super(LocalDate.class);
    }
    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        return LocalDate.parse(parser.readValueAs(String.class), DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(JiraService.DATE_PATTERN));
    }
}

public class LocalDateSerializer extends StdSerializer<LocalDate> {

    public LocalDateSerializer() {
        super(LocalDate.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDate value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        generator.writeString(value.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(JiraService.DATE_PATTERN)));
    }
}

@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
private LocalDate created;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hh` is for 1-12 hour format, use `HH` for 0-23 hour format, see [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) docs. You need:

```
public static final String DATE_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
```

Older classes like `SimpleDateFormat` or `Calendar` are [lenient](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)) by default so they are silently fixing the date by moving it forward by the overflowing field offset. That's why you are not supposed to use them anymore.

Comment: Is there a cleaner way to do the Jackson mappings?

Comment: @JGleason if you are using a framework like Spring Boot or other you may get some conventions out of the box e.g. ISO 8601 format. Otherwise you have to set it up yourself.

Comment: Humm using boot but not getting anything preloaded. I think I could use LocalDate out of the box if I wasn't using 24hrs. I Tried using Jackson annotations and declaring the DateTimeFormatter but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Check `org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat` annotation and Jackson properties available in Spring Boot properties.